# I got (ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression) or incorrect count/sum inside subquery

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery

I would like to make a query that will show me the total count and sum of sales, and for 2 workers in the same rows.

When I'm not using group by in a subquery I get a count for total sales for this worker not counted for each month. But when I try to use Group By clause in a subquery it shows me this error:

> PG::CardinalityViolation:
>   ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

And that makes sense but how I can count and sum amount of sales per month for each worker? Is there any possibility of transferring the value of Group By clause from query to a subquery? Should I be using subquery for this specific issue or maybe I can somehow make it easier?

```
SELECT 
    DATE_PART('month', payment_date) as month, 
    COUNT(payment_id) AS total_count,
    SUM(amount) AS total_amount,
    (SELECT COUNT(payment_id)
     FROM payment
     WHERE staff_id = 1
     GROUP BY DATE_PART('month', payment_date)) AS mike_count,
    (SELECT SUM(amount)
     FROM payment
     WHERE staff_id = 1
     GROUP BY DATE_PART('month', payment_date)) AS mike_amount,
    (SELECT COUNT(payment_id)
     FROM payment
     WHERE staff_id = 2
     GROUP BY DATE_PART('month', payment_date)) AS jon_count,
    (SELECT SUM(amount)
     FROM payment
     WHERE staff_id = 2
     GROUP BY DATE_PART('month', payment_date)) AS jon_amount
FROM 
    payment
GROUP BY  
    DATE_PART('month', payment_date)
ORDER BY 
    DATE_PART('month', payment_date);
```

This is the outcome w/o the group by clause in subqueries:

```
month   |total_count    |total_amount   |mike_count |mike_amount    |jon_count  |jon_amount
2       |2016           |0.835184E4     |7292       |0.3025212E5    |7304       |0.3105992E5
3       |5644           |0.2388656E5    |7292       |0.3025212E5    |7304       |0.3105992E5
4       |6754           |0.2855946E5    |7292       |0.3025212E5    |7304       |0.3105992E5
5       |182            |0.51418E3      |7292       |0.3025212E5    |7304       |0.3105992E5
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation instead:

```
SELECT DATE_PART('month', payment_date) as month, 
       count(payment_id) AS total_count,
       SUM(amount) AS total_amount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN staff_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as  mike_count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN staff_id = 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as  mike_amount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN staff_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as jon_count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN staff_id = 2 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as jon_amount
FROM payment
GROUP BY DATE_PART('month', payment_date)
ORDER BY DATE_PART('month', payment_date);
```

`DATE_PART()` suggests that you are using Postgres.  If so, I would recommend the `FILTER` clause:

```
SELECT DATE_PART('month', payment_date) as month, 
       COUNT(payment_id) AS total_count,
       SUM(amount) AS total_amount,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE staff_id = 1) as  mike_count,
       SUM(amount) FILTER (WHERE staff_id = 1) as  mike_amount,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE staff_id = 2) as jon_count,
       SUM(amount) FILTER (WHERE staff_id = 2) as jon_amount
FROM payment
GROUP BY DATE_PART('month', payment_date)
ORDER BY DATE_PART('month', payment_date);
```